# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to take the input "name" and find the whitespace so that I can find the first and last letter of the first and last name entered. But it's telling me "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." Help?

```
$name = Read-Host "Please enter the zip of person $count"
$length = $name.Length
$name = $name.split(" ")
write-host $name[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure which is causing you to get the null value error. But to get the first and last name just use this:

```
$name = "John Smith"    
$name = $name.split(" ")
$name[0] #outputs John
$name[1] #outputs Smith
```

Also you want `write-host` or `write-output` not print

Comment: Cool,  that works! So whats the method for finding specific characters out of strings again in powershell?

Comment: well you were on the right track you can do `indexof("J")` which will give you the position in the the string where the letter J is.

Comment: Well the problem with that would be I don't know what the $name variable is going to be until after a person inputs it.

Comment: Well I dont know what character you are looking for but if you want say the first character of the first name you could do `$name[0].substring(0,1)` which will give you the first letter of the first name

Comment: Right, so when I try to use the split method, and write-host $name[0], it's only returning the first character of the split string. So if I input "Brandon Smith" it's printing "B". That's not right is it?

Comment: Are you doing `$name = $name.split(" ")`?  it works for me no problem

Comment: Yeah check out the updated question, that's what I have now. Only returning first character of string

Comment: I figured it out finally. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You made a significant change to your post. It used to be:

```powershell
$name = Read-Host "Please enter the name of person $count"
$length = $name.Length

$pos = $name.IndexOf('\s')
print $pos
```

Lets ignore the `$length` line since you do not use it. It looks like you are trying to split on the first white space using regular expressions. You are using `.IndexOf()` which if you examine the overloads will see it expects strings or a char. Not earth shattering but the point is it is looking for string literals and does not support regular expressions. Consider the following statements

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Cameron> "John Smith".IndexOf('\s')
-1

PS C:\Users\Cameron> "John\sSmith".IndexOf('\s')
4
```

The first returned -1 since the string `\s` was not found. Then we put that string between John and Smith and we now get a positive return since the string *literal* was matched.

What you were possibly trying to do was use the `-split` which I base on your original question and the edit. `-split` supports regular expressions.

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Cameron> $name = "John        Smith"

PS C:\Users\Cameron> ($name -split '\s+')[0]
John
```

What the second line of code did was split the string `$name` on the **group** of white-space. We returned the first element which would be 'John'. The second, not shown since it should be obvious is 'Smith'. Neither elements have trailing or leading white-space ( based only on this example. Mileage will vary on other strings.)

Also, the command `print` is and alias for `Out-Printer`. Doubt you meant that command and were most likely looking for, like Dane Boulton suggested, `Write-Host` or `Write-Output`. Note: Look them up to understand an important difference. Former writes to console where the ladder writes to the output stream.

Lastly good guess would be that the error was caused by `$name` being null at the time `$name.IndexOf('\s')` was called. Easy to simulate as well.

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Cameron> $something = $null

PS C:\Users\Cameron> $something.Method()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $something.Method()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```